# TCP ACK response taking 10ms delay

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, delay, throughput

I am writing a client application that should receive files from a server. The communication uses a quite simple proprietary protocol designed over TCP: the server sends a chunk of 16KB of data, waits for a simple response from my client, and then proceeds to the next chunk; this is done until the file is fully transmitted.

The server is running on Windows. If I run my client on Windows (via Cygwin) I achieve a throughput of 70Mbits/s. But, if I run it on Linux, the maximum throughput I can get is 5Mbits/s (both tests using the same 100Mb Ethernet link).

After some investigation on tcpdump traces that I have collected, I found that Linux is taking about 10ms to answer each TCP ACK. I've tried to disabled the sockoption TCP_QUICKACK every time after I call recv(), but without success. I have not find any other TCP options that could change this behavior (under bsd sockets or even under Linux).

Can anyone help me to figure out what is happening?

1. My client was written in C++, using BSD sockets. TCP_NODELAY sockoption is set on it.
2. My linux Kernel is 2.6.19
3. The proprietary protocol and the server is not mine, so I can not change them in any way.

Below there is a sample of the tcpdump trace that I analysed. This is a chunk transmission. The server IP is 10.200.252.1 and the client is 10.200.252.2. The lines beginning with `**` are the TCP ACK packets with 10ms delay:

```
   5184 28.060969   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4736738 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5185 28.060978   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4738182 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5186 28.060981   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4739626 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5187 28.060987   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4741070 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5188 28.060990   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4742514 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5189 28.060994   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4743958 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5190 28.060997   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4745402 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5191 28.061000   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4746846 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5192 28.061003   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4748290 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5193 28.061007   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4749734 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5194 28.061038   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      1510   search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4751178 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=1444 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
   5195 28.061042   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      572    search-agent > 58358 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4752622 Ack=1741 Win=66048 Len=506 TSval=2951472 TSecr=2921060
 **5196 28.068422   10.200.252.2          10.200.252.1          TCP      66     58358 > search-agent [ACK] Seq=1741 Ack=4742514 Win=64512 Len=0 TSval=2921061 TSecr=2951472
 **5197 28.078479   10.200.252.2          10.200.252.1          TCP      66     58358 > search-agent [ACK] Seq=1741 Ack=4753128 Win=64512 Len=0 TSval=2921062 TSecr=2951472
   5198 28.082418   10.200.252.2          10.200.252.1          TCP      70     58358 > search-agent [PSH, ACK] Seq=1741 Ack=4753128 Win=64512 Len=4 TSval=2921062 TSecr=2951472
   5199 28.082675   10.200.252.2          10.200.252.1          TCP      68     58358 > search-agent [PSH, ACK] Seq=1745 Ack=4753128 Win=64512 Len=2 TSval=2921062 TSecr=2951472
   5200 28.082714   10.200.252.1          10.200.252.2          TCP      66     search-agent > 58358 [ACK] Seq=4753128 Ack=1747 Win=66048 Len=0 TSval=2951474
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the chunking and the application ACKs altogether. Just have one final one at the end of the file if you must. TCP already does chunking and ACKs and you are driving it crazy, for example it has to ACK the ACKS. There's no need for all this complexity. It's a streaming protocol: use it like one.

Comment: The protocol is not mine to change. I have to use it

Comment: Even if it would greatly improve the throughput on all platforms?

Comment: Unfortunately. I do not have access either to the server or the protocol.